# Not getting the expected value while overloading >>. What am I doing wrong here?

Tags: c++, function, operator-overloading, cin

I am a beginner in C++ and learning it. I am working on operator overloading now. In the below code, I have overloaded >> to get the class values as input. However, I cannot get to convert the value as described in the constructor. Is there any way to do as it gets converted as coded inside the constructor. Below is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Time
{
private:
    int hour;
    int minute;
    int second;

public:
    Time()
    {
        Time(0,0,0);
    }

    Time(int hh, int mm, int ss)
    {
        second = ss%60;
        mm +=ss/60;

        minute = mm%60;
        hh +=mm/60;

        hour = hh;
    }

    friend istream& operator>>(istream &in, Time &t1);

    int GetHour()    {        return hour;    }
    int GetMinute()     {        return minute;    }
    int GetSecond()     {        return second;    }
};

istream& operator >>(istream &in, Time &tm)
{
    in >> tm.hour;
    in >> tm.minute;
    in >> tm.second;

    return in;
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    Time tm;
    cin >> tm;

    cout << tm.GetHour() << ":" << tm.GetMinute() << ":" << tm.GetSecond();

    return 0;
}
```

In the above, whatever the value I enter, the same gets printed as output instead of the statements in the constructor.

Comment: That makes sense since the member variables of `tm` get updated by the values you input.

Comment: Here, I do not see any point in using >> other than getting inputs as I cannot change the value stored

Comment: The `operator>>` function is doing the right thing. If you need to modify the object, you'll need to add member functions to the class. I am a bit unclear what you are trying to accomplish and where you see a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're default constructing `tm`, then using your overloaded operator to fill the fields in it.  Your 3 parameter constructor is not getting called.